# После include header.html появилась 1!

Tags: php, html, html5

Дабы сократить время верстки множества страниц решил вынести `header` в отдельный файл, чтобы в `index.php` и других страницах призывать его через `include`.
Проблема в том, после вышесказанного появляется 1 после include-кода
Никаких "единичек" в коде у меня нет.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Единичка после include!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?= include_once ("header.html"); ?>
<main>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html:

```html
<header>
    <div class="header__inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row--inner">
                <div class="logo-link">
                    <a title="Главная" href="#">
                        <img src="images/logo_fake.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="heading">
                    <h1>Аренда ямобуров №1 в Москве и области!</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-number">
                    <div class="contact__row">
                        <img src="images/call_icon_medium.png" alt="call">
                        <div class="contact-text contact-text__first">+7 (925) 670 90 44</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact__row">
                        <img src="images/email_icon_medium.png" alt="email">
                        <div class="contact-text">studiorain27@gmail.com</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="header__nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">Техника</a></li>
                <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
                <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">Наши работы</a></li>
                <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">Где мы работаем?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Касаемо css, никаких псевдоэлементов вроде :before или :after нет.

Comment: `<?= include_once` надо заменить на `<? include_once` или если короткие теги отключены `<?php include_once`.

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо, однако в предыдущих проектах в точно аналогичной ситуации запись <?= работала без изъянов. Или путаю. Почему <?= не сработала? И почему вы ответ в комменты залили)

Comment: Ну вот как проверите - приходите.

Comment: Кажется, понял, для такого варианта необходимо было окружить код php двойными кавычками обвернуть.

Comment: если мне память не изменяет то <?= используется для быстрой вставки переменной вместо `<? echo $var;?>`

Comment: <?= используется как вывод в поток инфы (типа echo и print) и include ничего по сути не возвращает как функция (просто подгружает файл) ну и  он если подгрузил и вывел 1. это вообще не определённое поведение. не страдайте таким))) вы написали покажи-ка мне результат include))

Comment: я соврал (сам никогда не задумывался о сравнении include) вот явно все показано когда он сработает, а когда нет https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php (так что 1 это результат успешной подгрузки хедера)

Comment: Дыааа, довольно интересно. Я попросту не ожидал такого расклада. А в целом приятно, что даёт знать о состояние подгруженности header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?=$foo ?>` является сокращением для `<?php echo $foo; ?>`.

Теперь взглянем на Ваш код, вы используете `<?= include_once ("header.html"); ?>`, тем самым выводите то, что возвращает функция `include_once("header.html")`, а возвращает она `True` либо `False`, в случае удачного или неудачного выполнения соответственно. Данные типа `Bool` в php как правило выводятся в виде `1` в случае удачного или ничего в случае неудачного выполнения. В вашем случае функция выполняется успешно и еденичка естественно выводится.

Предлагаю такой вариант решения:

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Единичка после include!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once ("header.html"); ?>
<main>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, благодарю! Это, разумеется, сработало)